# How to display more informations in error.tsx file in Nextjs 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I would like to display more than just one sentence(i.e. Error title, error description and error cause).

I tried to extend basic Error class and add there two custom properties, but I can't access them in error.tsx file. Any ideas how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

You should either try separating your data with signs or use `JSON.Stringify` here are examples of both:

Otion 1:

```
const errorString ="title:this is title&description:this is description&errorCode:501";

let listErrors=errorString.split("&");
listErrors=listErrors.map((er)=>er.split(":"));

let error = {}
listErrors.forEach((er)=>{
   error[er[0]]=er[1]
})

//esta seria tu salida
console.log(error)
```

Option 2:  `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`:

```
const infoError={
  title:"this is a Title",
  description:"this is a description",
  errorCode:"504",
}

const errorString=JSON.stringify(infoError)
///this pased to function error☝


///in error.tsx decode string
const resultError=JSON.parse(errorString)

console.log(resultError)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no error.tsx(js), just create the file (error.js) in the app folder with the following content; and try to solve it by code in such a manner that it:

```js
'use client' // Error components must be Client Components
```

Don't forget to install useSWR to have an appropriate solution.

Answer (score -1):

Check this [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling)

If you have no error.tsx(js), just create the file (error.js) in the `app` folder with the following content

```
'use client' // Error components must be Client Components
 
import { useEffect } from 'react'
 
export default function Error({ error, reset }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Log the error to an error reporting service
    console.error(error)
  }, [error])
 
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Something went wrong!</h2>
      <button
        onClick={
          // Attempt to recover by trying to re-render the segment
          () => reset()
        }
      >
        Try again
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Update:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr';

export default function Error({ error, reset }) {
  // Fetch data from your API
  const { data, error: apiError } = useSWR('/api/your-api-endpoint');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Log the error to an error reporting service
    console.error(error);
  }, [error]);

  // Optional: Handle API errors
  if (apiError) return <div>Failed to load data from API</div>;

  // Display API message if available, otherwise show a generic message
  const messageFromApi = data?.message || 'Something went wrong!';

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{messageFromApi}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => reset()}>
        Try again
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Dont forget to instal [useSWR](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/getting-started)

Comment: I have error.tsx file  The problem is that I can't pass to it any more data than just a simple error message.

Comment: Which data you like to push? fetch from api?